# Flutter app stops on launch when Firebase Analytics is added

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

I create an app using `flutter create --org com.myorganisation --project-name myProjectName myAppName`. By default, at the time of writing, it generates a Flutter project with the native parts written in Kotlin and Swift.

Everything is going fine -- I can launch the default app in Android on a real device. Then I start to get Firebase set up in the project. Following the instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup, I modify the project level and app level `build.gradle`, and add the relevant plugins to `pub spec.yaml`.

With `firebase_core` installed, the Android app still launches, but as soon as I add `firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6`, it stops on launch with no information in the Debug console and the Dart Dev Tools unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the project in Android Studio, I find the error message

> ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
>   The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
>   root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

So then going back into the project level `build.gradle` file, I changed

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}
```

to

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}
```

And that change allowed Firebase Analytics to work.